# Make ansible run a task in a playbook multiple times based on variables

Tags: ansible, selenium-ide

I am trying to use the Ansible URI Module to log into multiple webpages and check the environments are up and working.

At the moment, i want it to just log into 2 webpages (Peoplesoft envs), but i would like a vars file that i can add to each time i want to to check a new page.

This is what i have so far, but it doesnt seem to log into both pages, just 1 of them....any help woould be appreciated.

Playbook -

```
---
- name: Run Selenium Test Scripts
hosts: local
vars_files:
  - /etc/ansible/uri_module/vars_uri.yml

tasks:

  - name: Installing URI dependancy
    yum: name=python-httplib2.noarch state=present

  - name: Log into Webpage
    uri:
      url: http://{{appserver}}:{{port}}/{{dbname}}/signon.html
      method: POST
      body: "name={{userid}}&password={{password}}&enter=Sign%20in"
      with_file: /etc/ansible/uri_module/vars_uri.yml
```

Vars file

```
---
  - { name: 'dog', appserver: 'st1920', port: '8100', dbname: 'dbdog', userid: 'user', password: 'pass' }
  - { name: 'cat', appserver: 'st1921', port: '8300', dbname: 'dbcat', userid: 'user', password: 'pass' }
```

Output with -vvvv

```
ok: [local] => {"changed": false, "content_language": "en-US", "content_length": "1831", "content_type": "text/html", "date": "Thu, 13 Oct 2016 11:45:23 GMT", "invocation": {"module_args": {"backup": null, "body": "name=user&password=pass&enter=Sign%20in", "body_format": "raw", "content": null, "creates": null, "delimiter": null, "dest": null, "directory_mode": null, "follow": false, "follow_redirects": "safe", "force": null, "force_basic_auth": false, "group": null, "method": "POST", "mode": null, "owner": null, "password": null, "regexp": null, "remote_src": null, "removes": null, "return_content": false, "selevel": null, "serole": null, "setype": null, "seuser": null, "src": null, "status_code": [200], "timeout": 30, "url": "http://st1921:8300/dbcat/signon.html", "user": null, "validate_certs": true, "with_file": "/etc/ansible/uri_module/vars_uri.yml"}, "module_name": "uri"}, "last_modified": "Wed, 13 Aug 2014 11:42:42 GMT", "redirected": false, "server": "WebSphere Application Server/7.0", "status": 200}
```

Using the vars file, i want it to log into the dog environment, tell me its there, log into the cat environment, tell me its there. Then if i have a horse, frog, or what ever environment, i can keep adding to the vars file without adding to or changing the playbook. At the moment it only logs into cat and i dont know why. 
Have i goen down the right route with this? Is there a better way of doing it? With it not giving an error, im struggling to figure out the issue! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use `with_file` like that.

It would be cleaner to store the `vars_uri` dictonaries in a list like this:

```
---

vars_uri:
   - { name: 'dog', appserver: 'st1920', port: '8100', dbname: 'dbdog', userid: 'user', password: 'pass' }
   - { name: 'cat', appserver: 'st1921', port: '8300', dbname: 'dbcat', userid: 'user', password: 'pass' }
```

and loop over it with `with_items` like this:

```
---
# Run Selenium Test Scripts
hosts: local
vars_files:
  - /etc/ansible/uri_module/vars_uri.yml

tasks:

  - name: Installing URI dependancy
    yum: name=python-httplib2.noarch state=present

  - name: Log into Webpage
    uri:
      url: http://{{ item.appserver }}:{{ item.port }}/{{ item.dbname }}/signon.html
      method: POST
      body: "name={{ item.userid }}&password={{ item.password }}&enter=Sign%20in"
    with_items: vars_uri
```